# Replace _id with my own key from response

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am passing my response to a SQLite database and was working until I started to tie a Cursor adapter to the listview. Now when I try to save the data and pull it I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. I want to keep my Primary Key as a specific response because the web service calls are tied to the same number. Is there a way to keep my KEY_ID as the employee number but get rid of the _id error?

I want the key to be the employee number so I can grab that and populate just that employee into the listvie attached to the cursor adapter. Also will need that so I can remove those users from the other list that I want to populate under the first one.

My DatabaseHandler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employeeManager";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employee";

    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);

        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


        //Inserting Row
        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] {
                KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                    cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                    cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                    cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                    cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                    cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }

    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());

        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Where I create, add, and get the database

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTopList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(this, topViewList(mTopCursor));
        mTopList.setAdapter(topAdapter);

        directReportListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBottomListViewAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mEmployees);
        directReportListView.setAdapter(mBottomListViewAdapter);
        getBottomViewXMLData();


        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);

        //Top List View work
        //  mTopListViewAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(this, mEmployees);


    }

    public void getBottomViewXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                DatabaseHandler databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    databasehandler.addEmployee(e);
                }




                Log.i("ADAM", databasehandler.toString());

                mEmployees.clear();
                mEmployees.addAll(employees);


                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public Cursor topViewList(Cursor employeeCursor) {
        //always starts with Mark
        int startingEmployeeNumber = startingEmployeeNumber(int);
        DatabaseHandler mDatabase = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        mDatabase.getEmployee(startingEmployeeNumber);
        employeeCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM employee", null);

        return employeeCursor;
    }
}
```

TopListCursorAdapter

```
public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        TextView tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        ImageView mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        ImageView mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        CardView mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_cardView);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mPayrollTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mPicData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        //parse image from database
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mPicData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
        mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);

        tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        tvTitle.setText(mPayrollTitle);


        mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "This is working well here also", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know sql basics? `SELECT column1 AS alias1`

Comment: Thought you dont do SELECT onCreate of a database? Am I able to do that in the databasehandler or do I have to do that  Cursor?

Comment: No, I wasn't wrote about select in the onCreate...  I was talking about select when you are obtaining the cursor for cursoradapter

Comment: I added my adapter to orginal post. I am using getColumnIndexOrThrow and setting a textView to each item I want to display in a CardView. Do I need a SELECT statement in the adapter?

Comment: How do you create the `Cursor` which is send to your custom `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: Cursor employeeCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT  Employee_number AS _id", null); But this seems to not work, very new to databases and curor so still figuring this all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the Android API widgets that interact with a SQLite database assume the `Cursor` contains a column named `_id`. You have at least two choices to work around this error:

1. Add a column named `_id`. You can make it include the same data as `Employee_number`. The easiest way to do this is `SELECT Employee_number AS _id`.
2. Avoid using the parts of the Android API that uses `_id` and write your own versions of these methods.

Comment: I will try the first one as seems easier as I am new to database period and using cursors in Android

Comment: Think I will try to start over because I have clearly missed something and I am not fully understanding how all this ties in together.

Comment: @AdamGardner Good luck! Feel free to post more questions after you have tried some things and need more help.